# Will a web browser ever send a request with the Transfer-Encoding header?

Tags: google-chrome, http, firefox, browser, transfer-encoding

### Note

- This question is about *requests* with the `Transfer-Encoding` header, *not responses*
- Yes, requests can use the `Transfer-Encoding` header

  - [`Transfer-Encoding` is a `general-header`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-14.41)
  - [`Requests` may use `general-header`s](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-5)
- One could implement a web browser that does *anything*, but for the purposes of this question, please limit the definition of "web browser" to Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Microsoft Edge, and Apple Safari.

### Background

- For `XMLHttpRequest`, `Transfer-Encoding` is a [forbidden header name](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name)
- For `fetch`, `Transfer-Encoding` is a [forbidden header name](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name)
- For links or forms in HTML, there is no explicit reference to `Transfer-Encoding` in [the HTML standard] (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/)
- It's not an authoritative source, but [the PortSwigger article on request smuggling](https://portswigger.net/web-security/request-smuggling) states that "Browsers do not normally use chunked encoding in requests, and it is normally seen only in server responses."
- The only reference I've been able to find that might use `Transfer-Encoding` is Chrome-specific, [is behind an experimental flag](https://web.dev/fetch-upload-streaming/#enable-flags), and requires [a second, non-standard flag to enable it for HTTP/1.1](https://web.dev/fetch-upload-streaming/#http2-only-by-default)

### Question

- Is there a case (or cases) where a web browser will make a request with the `Transfer-Encoding` header?

Answer (score 1):

I have been researching this topic recently and my understanding is that this is currently not supported by any major browser, **but** it is work-in-process.

The Chrome experiment is a first try to see how it will play out in web-world as it seems there are quite some edge cases that could go wrong with the complex web infrastructure there is out there (load balancers, proxies etc).

The main source I have been reading up on this is this [`fetch`'s issue about readable stream support](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/966), that I recommend to read about if you are interested.